# Tracing Python Program

Tags: python

I am trying to trace execution of a python script:

```
python -m trace --count nmt.nmt \
--src=de --tgt=en \
--ckpt=deen_gnmt_model_4_layer/translate.ckpt \
--hparams_path=nmt/standard_hparams/wmt16_gnmt_4_layer.json \
--out_dir=/tmp/deen_gnmt \
--vocab_prefix=/tmp/wmt16/vocab.bpe.32000 \
--inference_input_file=/tmp/wmt16/newstest2015.tok.bpe.32000.de \
--inference_output_file=/tmp/deen_gnmt/output_infer \
--inference_ref_file=/tmp/wmt16/newstest2015.tok.bpe.32000.en
```

However, I receive the nmt.nmt: Cannot run file 'nmt.nmt' because: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nmt.nmt' Error. When I take the tracing command out, it works. Does anyone have a solution on why I can execute script with trace?

Comment: Did the original command (without `trace`) look like `python nmt.nmt ...` or `python -m nmt.nmt ...`?

Comment: The original command worked with -m nmt.nmt

Answer (score 0):

Your original command used `python -m nmt.nmt ...`, which tells Python to locate the `nmt.nmt` module and run it as the main script.

Your `trace` command is using `python -m trace ...`, telling Python to run the `trace` module as the main script, and telling `trace` to run a *file* in the current directory named `nmt.nmt` as the main script. There is no such file; the `nmt.nmt` module corresponds to an `nmt.py` file in an `nmt` directory somewhere on your `sys.path`, not an `nmt.nmt` file.

The `trace` module does not offer its own equivalent of `python -m`; you cannot tell the `trace` module to run another module as the main script and trace it. One workaround might be to create a file that replicates the effect of `python -m` and trace that. I have not tested this:

```
# workaround.py
import runpy

runpy.run_module('nmt.nmt', run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)
```

This would be traced as `python -m trace --count workaround.py ...`

Comment: Thanks a lot! How would I incorporate the command line arguments? Would I just add them in single quite in the first argument of run_module?

Comment: @DonquiseParker: Pass them on the command line after `workaround.py`. (I don't know if this will actually work; I don't know how the `trace` module interacts with `runpy`, and like I said, I haven't tested it.)

Answer (score 0):

Find out the full path of the package or module you're running by running one or more of the following;

`python -vm nmt.nmt |& grep nmt` or

The output should be something like;

```
import nmt # directory /home/user/src/nmt
import nmt # precompiled from /home/user/nmt/__init__.pyc
import nmt.nmt # directory /home/user/nmt/nmt
```

`python -c 'import nmt.nmt;print(nmt.nmt.__file__)'`
Tho output should be an absolute path of the module which you can trace by `python -m trace --trace /home/user/nmt/nmt.py`

`python -c 'import nmt.nmt;print(nmt.nmt.__path__)'`
The output should be an absolute path of the directory which you can trace by 
`python -m trace --trace /home/user/nmt/nmt/__main__.py`

Because directories with `__init__.py` can be run by `python -m` if they contain `__main__.py`.

Comment: That's going to screw up the import system, including breaking relative imports.

Comment: @user2357112 elucidate and give official refs